# Show that $M(\xi)$ is invertible.

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis

Here is an exercice in my functional analysis course that I'm really stuck on:

Let $d, n \in \mathbb N_0$ and $a_{\alpha, \beta, i, j}$ such that $1 \le \alpha, \beta \le d$ and $1 \le i,j \le n$. Let us suppose that there exists $\nu > 0$ such that for every $M \in \text{Mat}_{d\times n}( \mathbb R)$ of rank $\le 1$, we have
$$\sum_{\alpha, \beta, i, j} a_{\alpha, \beta, i, j} M_{\alpha i} M_{\beta j} > \nu \text{tr}(MM^T).$$
Now, for $\xi \in \mathbb R^d$, we define $M(\xi) \in\mathcal L (\mathbb C^n)$ (linear map from $\mathbb C^n$ to $\mathbb C^n$) such that
$$(M(\xi) z)_j  = \sum_{\alpha, \beta, j} a_{\alpha, \beta, i, j} \xi_\alpha \xi_\beta z_j.$$
In this case, we should be able to show that $\text{Id}_{\mathbb C^n} + M(\xi)$ is invertible but I have really no idea how to do that. I though that it would be possible by using the fact that all element of $B_{\mathcal L(\mathbb C^n)}(\text{Id}_{\mathbb C^n}, 1)$ are invertible. Therefore, we just have to show that $\|M(\xi)\|_{\mathcal L(\mathbb C^n)} < 1$ but
\begin{align}
\|M(\xi)\|_{\mathcal L(\mathbb C^n)} &= \sup_{\|z\| \le 1} \|M(\xi)(z)\|_{\mathbb C^n}\\
&= \sup_{\|z\| \le 1} \sum_{\alpha , \beta, i, j} |a_{\alpha, \beta, i, j} \xi_\alpha \xi_\beta z_j|
\end{align}
and from here I do not see how conclude. Does anyone know how to show the invertibility of $\text{Id}_{\mathbb C^n} + M(\xi)$ ?